# How do I change the third person view from the right shoulder to the left shoulder in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Haven't been able to find the answer anywhere, so sorry if this is a duplicate, I must've missed it in that case.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Pretty sure you can't do that, at least on Xbox. Since mods and the console are available on PC, it's usually a good idea to indicate your platform on Skyrim questions.

Answer (score 4):

If you’re on PC, you can download the [Customizable Camera](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/37347/?) mod to adjust the camera however you want. I haven’t tried it, but it looks like it works.

If you’re on a console, there’s nothing you can do.